# php form checkbox='$variable'

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I can't seem to get this done.  I'm getting data from a table, if the value in the column = y then the checkbox must be checked, if the value in the column = n, the checkbox must not be checked, all the checkboxes stays checked, even though only the first row's column = y

```
<?php
session_start();
    include 'datalogin.php';
    $sel_course_id = 2;
    $sel_date_1    = '2012-05-21';
    $sel_date_2    = '2012-05-22';
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<strong>Completed the course</strong>";

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM trn WHERE course_id = '$sel_course_id' AND date_1 = '$sel_date_1' and date_2 = '$sel_date_2'";
    $res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
        $rowid1           = $row1['id'];
        $uid1              = $row1['usr_id'];
        $certificate_name1 = $row1['certificate_name'];
        $course_completed1 = $row1['course_completed'];

            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE id = '$uid1'";
            $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
                $fn2 = $row2['firstname'];
                $ln2 = $row2['lastname'];
            } 
            $checked2 = "";
            if ($course_completed1 == y) {
                $checked2 = "checked";
            } 
            if ($course_completed1 == n) {
                $checked2 = "";
            } 
            echo "<input name='question[$rowid1][]' type='checkbox'  checked='$checked2' value='1' />$fn2 $ln2";
echo "</br>";
   } 
    echo "</form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned, you need to quote `y` and `n` to compare string values. But even just having `checked=""` will result in your checkbox being checked. Try making your statements like this instead:

```
if ($course_completed1 == "y") {
    $checked2 = "checked='checked'";
} 
elseif ($course_completed1 == "n") {
    $checked2 = "";
}

echo "<input name='question[$rowid1][]' type='checkbox' $checked2 value='1' />$fn2 $ln2";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes for strings:

```
if ($course_completed1 == "y") {
    $checked2 = "checked";
} 
if ($course_completed1 == "n") {
    $checked2 = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`checked='$checked2'` should be plain `$checked2`, it is a boolean attribute.

(Unless you are writing XHTML in which case it should also be given the value `'checked="checked"` after you test `if ($course_completed1 == "y") {`).

Your tests should also be checking strings (`"y"`) and not constants (`y`).